# objective c - static variables puzzling behavior

Tags: objective-c, c, static

In an .h file I have the following line (outside of any @interface block):

`static NSMutableDictionary *dictLookup;`

In the corresponding .m file I try to initialize that static in the `init` method of the class:

`dictLookup = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];`

`dictLookup setValue:@"Hello?" forKey:@"Goodbye"];`

However, when I insert breakpoints and do checks, dictLookup never becomes anything other than nil.

Also, I get a bizarre warning "Unused variable dictLookup" at compile time.  Bizarre because if I delete the static declaration, then I get an "Undeclared identifier" compiler error at the lines in the `init` method.

I've since discovered there are better ways of doing what I want.  But what was going on here?  (1) Why can't I set dictLookup to anything?

Some sources seem to say that in C a static variable can only be used in the file in which it is declared.  (2) If so, then why doesn't compiler fail with an error in the .m file?  Given (1) that would seem to be the logical thing to design the compiler to do.

And (3) When I designed a new 'test' project from scratch, with a new .h/.m file combo like the one described, I WAS able to set dictLookup and insert keys.  Why could accoutn for this difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. When you put a declaration of a `static` variable in a `.h` file, it gets re-defined in every `.m` file from which the header is included. A brand-new variable will be created in each file, with the same name.
2. This is not an error in the `.m` file: the variable is local to that file, and invisible to the linker, so there are no "multiple definitions" error.
3. That's because your test project used a single `.m` file.

> Some sources seem to say that in C a static variable can only be used in the file in which it is declared.

That is absolutely correct: a `static` variable is very much like a file-scoped global variable, it should be defined in the `.m` file. If you want to share a variable, it needs to be a global then. *Declare* it in the header with the `extern` keyword, like this

```
extern NSMutableDictionary *dictLookup;
```

and then *define* it in one of the `.m` files like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictLookup;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still not sure why dictLookup, in same-file scope, never became anything other than nil (according to the debugger) but my computer crashed soon after and when I now try to reproduce this I can't.